# du command combined with find -mmin

Tags: disk-usage, size

I want to have an idea of how much archivelogs the database is generating daily, so I did:

`find /u02/archivelog -mmin -1440 | du -sh` and got 220GB, which is the total size of all files in that directory, and not only less than 1 day total.

If instead I did `find /u02/archivelog -mmin -1440 -exec ls -ltrh {} \;` This would work and list only the files less than 1 day. But the logic does not seem to apply with `du`.

How can I improve the syntax in order to get expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

du doesn't seem to accept files piped into it. I think what you're looking for is

```
find /u02/archivelog -type f -mmin -1440 -exec du -ch {} +
```

Using the `+` instead of the `;` makes find build up `{}` as a list and executes once, instead of executing once for each match.
You also need to use `-type f`, otherwise it'll match the directory itself, which is modified every time a new file is added. If you include the directory itself in the du, you're going to wind up with the size of all files again.
The `-c` makes du show a "total" line as well. If you only want the total, you can add `| tail -1` to the end.

Comment: Thank you for the help and concepts. It worked as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `{} \;` limits the argument of `ls` to one element. If you are interested in the total of the archive logs you could use:

```
find /u02/archivelog -mmin -1440 -type f -exec wc -c {} + | tail -1
```

To get the total number of bytes for the files under that directory.

Where the `{} +` puts as many filenames on the commandline presented to `wc` as the system allows (so there is a possibility that `wc` will be called multiple times if you have a many files and/or extremely long filenames).

Comment: Thanks. This method also worked just fine and did the trick.